# Unbiased Estimator of the truncation points in a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, truncation, truncated-normal-distribution

Consider the variables  $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2,a,b)$ iid with truncation points $a$ and $b$, i.e. $a < x_i < b$.

Suppose all four parameters, namely $\mu, \sigma, a, b$ are unknown.

Are there unbiased estimators for $a$ and $b$?

In practice what is the best approach to obtain unbiased estimators for $a$ and $b$?

**MLEs are biased**

I can show that the maximum likelihood estimators are biased. In fact we can see that

$$\hat{a}_{MLE} = \min(x_i)$$ and $$\hat{b}_{MLE} = \max(x_i)$$

Clearly $\hat{a}_{MLE}$ is an over-estimate and $\hat{b}_{MLE}$ an under-estimate.

**There is an unbiased estimator for $\Phi^{-1}(\frac{b- \mu}{ \sigma})$**

It is well known that if $y_i \sim \text{Unif}(0,\lambda)$ then
$$ \hat{\lambda} = \frac{n+1}{n}\max(y_i)$$
is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\lambda}) = \lambda$.

Let $\Phi$ be the standard normal CDF, using the above result and the fact that
$$\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \sim \text{Unif}\!\left(0,\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{b- \mu}{ \sigma}\right)\right)$$
we get that
$$\frac{n+1}{n}\max\left(\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)$$
is an unbiased estimator for $$\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{b- \mu}{ \sigma}\right).$$

However clearly one can not simply solve for $b$ in the above to get an unbiased estimator for $b$. Also $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown hence it complicates the estimation further in practice.

Comment: You should check the last part, I don't think its correct. I can see no other solution than maybe something approximate based on simulation.

Comment: Suppose we set $a=0$ for simplicity. I expect that the estimator for $b$ would be of the form $f(\sum x_i,\sum x_i^2,\max x_i)$. To prove that $f$ is unbiased, we would need to integrate $f$ against a distribution for those three parameters. What is that distribution -- i.e. what is $P\left[\sum x_i < R, \sum x_i^2 < S, \max x_i < T\ \big|\ x_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma,0,b)\right]$?